# Configure a camera to chase a flying drone with realistic lag?

Tags: animation, camera, constraints, parent, tracking

I'm animating a flying drone, adding noise via the graph editor to make it wobble and such like a drone flying through shifting air currents. Now I'd like to add a chase camera a few feet behind the drone with it's own realistic motion.

I know how to make the camera track a moving object by parenting or adding a tracking constraint, but the results are too rigid, looking as though the camera is attached to the drone via a rigid pole. I want something more elastic, as though the camera is attached to the drone via an invisible rubber band or bungee cord. Is there a way to do this? Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11